# How to redirect from node view to node edit page in a view?

Tags: views, nodes

I need on of the views in my Drupal design, which is using node title linked to the node content view, just redirect form **node content view page** to that **node edit page**.

How would it be possible? If it needs coding please write the code. Thanks

(My Drupal version is 7.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to achieve:

Add new field: **'nid'**

- Add nid field to view above the title field.
- Exclude nid from display.
- Goto arrangement and put it above the title field, so that it can fetch it.

Change to existing field: **'title'**

- Open title field settings.
- Uncheck Link this field to the original piece of content.
- Expand `REWRITE RESULTS` section.
- Check `Output this field as a link checkbox`.
- Put `node/[nid]/edit` to the `Link path` input.